# SolrCloud DIH implementation with zookeeper

Tags: solr, solrcloud, dih

I am going to put my old DataImportHandler configuration of solr 4.3 to SolrCloud 5.0.

I have already deployed zookeeper on 3 virtual machines and all are well communicating with each other. I have read about nodes, collections, shards and replicas but I am not able to collect how I can put my old DIH configurations to zookeeper. Currently I have 5 different DIH configurations which I need to put into solrCloud. Is that mean I have to create 5 nodes or collections?, yup I am confused here.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of extra node for configuration. Solr Cloud depends upon collection which is sharded across the nodes and you can create replica of it.

These are the Steps you need to do for SolrCloud :-

1. Run Zookeeper
2. Run Solrnodes with zookeeper
3. Upload configuration to zookeeper
4. Create collection by referring to the configuration

To upload configuration to zookeeper and create collection :-

1. Create a solrlibs directory
2. Copy /opt/solr/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/* to it
3. Copy /opt/solr/server/lib/ext/* to it
4. Run the command `java -classpath .:/opt/solrlibs/* org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkCLI -cmd upconfig -zkhost 192.168.1.1:2181,192.168.1.2:2181,192.168.1.3:2181 -confdir /opt/solrconfigs/test/conf -confname testconf`
5. Create the collection using following command `http://192.168.1.4:8080/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=test&collection.configName=testconf&numShards=2&replicationFactor=2`
6. Num Shards and Replication factor will be based on number of nodes you have.

Comment: first up all thanks! my query is if I have multiple DIH configurations, is I need to move all configuration folders to `/opt/solrconfigs/test/conf` folder alng with solr.xml?

Comment: in the conf folder create 5 db-data-config-*.xml. * refers to 1,2,3,4,5. Now in solrconfig.xml add request handler for dataimport like, /dataimport1 refers to db-data-config-1.xml

Comment: it means in conf folder there should be only 1 solrconfig.xml, 5 DIH-config.xml but what about schema.xml? each should have own schema.xml

Comment: there will be only one schema.xml for a collection. if you want to use multiple dih then u can make multiple db-data-config.xml. If your requirement is to make multiple schema and multiple dih then u need to create that no of collections otherwise only one collection with one schema.xml and multiple dih si fine.